# Hash equivalent of large array search

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a large array `$actor_movie_array`, which is sorted in this manner:

```
[actor1, movie1, movie2, movie3...]
[actor2, movie1, movie2, movie3...]
[actor3, movie1, movie2...]
```

The following method takes in a parameter `actor_name`, and then searches through `$actor_movie_array` for `actor_name`:

```
def search by actor(actor_name)  
    result_array = Array.new  
        $actor_movie_array.each {  
        |x| if x[0] == actor_name  
            result_array = x  
            result_array.delete_at(0)  
            break  
        end  
    }  
    return result_array  
end
```

If found, it will be pushed into an empty array `result_array` that looks like this:

```
result_array = [actor1, movie1, movie2, movie3...]
```

Then, I will delete the first index of the array, which in this case is `actor1`, as I only want the remaining movies by this actor left in `result_array`.

However, this is really inefficient. I know that the hash equivalent would be more efficient, but do not know how to do it. Could anyone help to translate this into a hash equivalent?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a hash with `actor1`, `actor2`, etc. as keys and the movie arrays as values? That seems a bit on the simple side, but I don't know how else to interpret your question.

Comment: Yes, and then do the search, if actor not found it returns an empty array. If actor found, it keeps all the movies of that actor in an array.

Comment: The `search_by_actor` method can be replaced by `$actor_movie_array.assoc(actor_name)`.[(docs)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as below

```
array_of_array = [ %w[actor1 movie1 movie2 movie3],
                   %w[actor2 movie1 movie2 movie3],
                   %w[actor3 movie1 movie2]
                 ]

def search(ary,actor_name)
  match = ary.find { |a| a.first == actor_name }
  match.nil? ? "no actor found" : match[1..-1] 
end

search(array_of_array,'actor2')
# => ["movie1", "movie2", "movie3"]

search(array_of_array,'actor5')
# => "no actor found"
```

Or, take the below approach :

```
array_of_array = [ %w[actor1 movie1 movie2 movie3],
                   %w[actor2 movie1 movie2 movie3],
                   %w[actor3 movie1 movie2]
                 ]
hsh = Hash[ary.map { |key,*val| [key,val] }]

def search(hash,actor_name)
  hash.fetch(actor_name,"no actor found")
end

search(hsh,'actor2')
# => ["movie1", "movie2"]

search(hsh,'actor5')
# => "no actor found"
```

Comment: Constructing a Hash from the full contents of the array every time you want to look something up will undoubtedly be slower than just searching.

Comment: @Chuck Yes,, You are right. I did it by mistake, put it inside the method. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, assuming you have a Hash of the form `actors_to_movies = {actor1 => [movie1, movie2, movie3], actor2 => [movie4, movie5, movie6]}`, you can just loop up lists of movies by actor the same way you'd look up anything in a Hash — for example `actors_to_movies[actor1]` would give `[movie1, movie2, movie3]`.

If you're trying to figure out how to generate a hash from an array of the form you have, you'd do it like this:

```
actors_to_movies = Hash[ $actor_movie_array.map {|key, *vals| [key, vals] } ]
```

(Note that transforming a large array into a hashmap will take even longer than searching the array — but you'll ideally only have to do it once.)